# how to play m3u8 files in angular2

Tags: angular, media-player, flowplayer, m3u8

Im building a hybrid app which plays music of the format m3u8 using angular2. The initial version of the app was written in pure javascript and flowplayer was used to play the music. Support for angular2 is not explicitly mentioned in flowplayer docs. How can i play m3u8 files? Is there any player that is available for angular2? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

[videogular2](https://github.com/videogular/videogular2) (The HTML5 video player for Angular 2) should be an option for you.

Comment: It doesn't work in the actual Angular version :(